# Trying out Bean definition inheritance in Spring but it didn't work out as expected

Tags: java, spring

I am just dabbling with Spring framework. Here I was trying out the "parent" attribute in the bean declaration,

This is my code below for CommonCar.java:

```
package com.justPractise.ex01;

public class CommonCar {
    private String modelName;
    private String engine;

    public CommonCar(String modelName){
        this.modelName = modelName;
        System.out.println(" PARAMETERISED "+this.getClass().getName()+" INITIALISED..... ");
    }

    public CommonCar(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" INITIALISED..... ");
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return modelName;
    }

    public void setModelName(String modelName) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public String getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(String engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();
        strb.append("\nDEFAULT CAR ");
        strb.append(this.modelName);
        strb.append("\nENGINE NAME ");
        strb.append(this.engine);
        return strb.toString();     
    }

}
```

This the code below for CustomCar.java:

```
package com.justPractise.ex01;

public class CustomCar {
    private String modelName;
    private String engine;

    public CustomCar(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+" INITIALISED..... ");
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return modelName;
    }



    public void setModelName(String modelName) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public String getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(String engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();
        strb.append("\nDEFAULT CAR ");
        strb.append(this.modelName);
        strb.append("\nENGINE NAME ");
        strb.append(this.engine);
        return strb.toString();     
    }
}
```

This is the bean-jojo.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd" default-lazy-init="true">

         <bean class="com.justPractise.ex01.CommonCar" id="commonCAR">
            <constructor-arg value="TATA-SAFARI V30" />
            <property name="engine" value="2340 CC FOUR CYLINDER 1700 BHP ENGINE" />
         </bean>

         <bean class="com.justPractise.ex01.CustomCar" id="customCAR" parent="commonCAR">
            <property name="modelName" value="TOYOTA-INNOVA" />         
         </bean>                    

</beans>
```

This is the class with the main method, which I run from commandline:

```
package com.justPractise.ex01;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainPractise01 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = null;  
        CustomCar obj = null;
        try{
            ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean-jojo.xml");
            obj = (CustomCar) ctx.getBean("customCAR"); 
            System.out.println(obj);                        
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
    }

}
```

Now if I run the above programme, I get this error in the command prompt:

```
[java] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customCAR' defined in class path resource
[bean-jojo.xml]: 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'customCAR' (hint: specify index/type/name 
arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

But if I make the following changes to the bean-jojo.xml, my programme runs fine:

```
 <bean class="com.justPractise.ex01.CommonCar" id="commonCAR">
            <property name="modelName" value="TATA-SAFARI V30" />
            <property name="engine" value="2340 CC FOUR CYLINDER 1700 BHP ENGINE" />
         </bean>
```

This is the expected output I get by making the above change in xml:

```
[java] com.justPractise.ex01.CustomCar INITIALISED.....
[java]
[java] DEFAULT CAR TOYOTA-INNOVA
[java] ENGINE NAME 2340 CC FOUR CYLINDER 1700 BHP ENGINE
[echo] Java running completed
```

So, can you tell me why constructor args in the CommonCar declaration in bean-jojo.xml was not working?
Waiting for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception could not be more readable. Create a constructor in your customBean car that accepts a String (Spring will pass it `TATA-SAFARI V30`)

Your second example works because you no longer reference the `commonClass` superclass, so it is not defined a constructor with a parameter